# Hard drive enclosure for 2.5" Sata drive

Tags: macbook-pro, sata

I am not an Apple user myself, but trying to solve a problem for a family member.

His Macbook Pro is damaged and not economical to repair, however he would like the data off the hard drive.

Do I need to find a specific type of external hard drive enclosure, or will any standard 2.5" SATA enclosure work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MacBooks and other Apple computers that use 2.5" or 3.5" form factor drives are all standard SATA II or III, so any typical hard drive would work.